# Можно ли писать _штамм омикрон_ — без кавычек, со строчной?

Tags: приложение

Можно ли писать *штамм омикрон* — без кавычек, со строчной, так же как пишутся два нарицательных существительных, из которых первое обозначает родовое понятие, а второе — видовое?

Answer (score 3):

**Да, можно.** Рекомендация Грамоты.ру [такова](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=308994):

> *омикрон-штамм* (ср. гамма-лучи), *штамм омикрон* (ср. рукав реглан).